# Parse complex JSON to nested listed

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, listview

I am new to Flutter. I have a JSON file of four levels (company- models- years- parts). I 'am trying to read from that JSON file and display the company as a list and the models as sublist as in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf49C.png).

What I did so far is that

1- uploaded the JSON file to my Flutter Application added it to the assets in `.yaml` file.

```html
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "company": "Toyota",
    "models": [
      {
        "name": "LandCruiser",
        "image": "LC",
        "years": [
          {
            "name": "2009",
            "image": "LC2009.png",
            "parts": [
              {
                "name": "Plugs",
                "image": "plugs2009.png",
                "price": "$20"
              },
              {
                "name": "Windshield",
                "image": "WS2009.png",
                "price": "$40"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "2010",
            "image": "LC2010.png",
            "parts": [
              {
                "name": "Plugs",
                "image": "Plugs2010.png",
                "price": "$30"
              },
              {
                "name": "Windshiels",
                "image": "WS2010.png",
                "price": "$60"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "4Runner",
        "image": "4Runner.png",
        "years": [
          {
            "name": "2016",
            "image": "4R2016.png",
            "parts": [
              {
                "name": "injection",
                "image": "Inj2016.png",
                "price": "$10"
              },
              {
                "name": "Radiotor",
                "image": "Rad2016.png",
                "price": "$100.mp3"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "2020",
            "image": "4R2020.png",
            "parts": [
              {
                "name": "Alternator",
                "image": "Alt2020.png",
                "price": "$20"
              },
              {
                "name": "Starter",
                "image": "Star2020.png",
                "price": "$10"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Honda",
    "models": [
      {
        "name": "Civic",
        "image": "Civ2021",
        "years": [
          {
            "name": "2006",
            "image": "HC2006.png",
            "parts": [
              {
                "name": "Tires",
                "image": "HCT2006.png",
                "price": "$200"
              },
              {
                "name": "HeadLight",
                "image": "HCH2006.png",
                "price": "$55"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "2022",
            "image": "HC2022.png",
            "parts": [
              {
                "name": "Windshield",
                "image": "HCWS2022.png",
                "price": "$300"
              },
              {
                "name": "Backlights",
                "image": "HCBL2022.png",
                "price": "$200"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Accord",
        "image": "Accord.png",
        "years": [
          {
            "name": "2010",
            "image": "Acc2010.png",
            "parts": [
              {
                "name": "Backlights",
                "image": "HACC2010.png",
                "price": "$120"
              },
              {
                "name": "HeadLights",
                "image": "HACCHL2010.png",
                "price": "$200"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "2022",
            "image": "Acc2022.png",
            "parts": [
              {
                "name": "plugs",
                "image": "HACC2022.png",
                "Audio": "$400"
              },
              {
                "name": "Visor",
                "image": "HACCV2022.png",
                "Audio": "$50"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

2- Wrote the `model` for the JSON file.

```html
class CarParts {
  final int id;
  final String Company;
  final List<Models> models;

  CarParts({this.id, this.name, this.model});

  factory CarParts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>json){
    return CarParts(
      id: json['id'],
      Company: json['Company'],
      Models: parsemodels(json),
    );
  }
  static List<Models> parsemodels(modelsJson) {
    var list = modelsJson['Models'] as List;
    List<Models> modelsList = list.map((data) => Models.fromJson(data))
        .toList();
    return modelsList;
  }
}
class Models{
  String name;
  String image;
  Models({this.name,this.image});
  factory Models.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>parsedJson){
    return Models(
        name: parsedJson['name'],
        image: parsedJson['image']);
  }
}
```

3- added the following to `main.dat` to read the JSON file.

```html
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<String> loadCarfromAssets() async{
    return await  rootBundle.loadString('jsons/carparts.json');
  }

  Future loadCarparts() async{
    String jsonString = await loadCarfromAssets();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    Carparts carparts = new Carparts.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    loadCarparts();
  }
```

4- How can I map the JSON file to expansion tile and list tile in `main.dart`?

I did it in a static way but don't know how to fed listView Builder, Expansion tile, and list tile from the list I got from reading the JSON file to Exapnsiontile and list tile.

```html
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

       debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, // For Arabic language
          child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(" Car Parts"),
          ),
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                                    UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                      accountName: Text('Ali',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 18,color: Colors.black),),
                      accountEmail: Text('sa@gmail.com'),
                      currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(child: Image.asset('Image/boy.png', width: 40,height: 40), ),
                  ),

                  ListTile(
                    leading: Image.asset('Image/logout.png', width: 40,height: 40),
                    title:  const  Text("Exit",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 18,color: Colors.black),),
                    onTap: (){SystemNavigator.pop(); },
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ),
          //endDrawer: Drawer(),
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
              child:ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height:0.0),
                    ExpansionTile(
                      leading: Image.asset('Image/square-root.png', width: 40,height: 40),
                      title: const Text("Toyota",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20,color: Colors.black),),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Image.asset('Image/square-root.png', width: 30,height: 30),
                          title: const Text("LandCruier",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 16,color: Colors.brown),),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
                          onTap: (){
                          },
                        ),
                        Divider(),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Image.asset('Image/cone.png', width: 30,height: 30),
                          title: const Text("4Runner",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 16,color: Colors.brown),),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
                          onTap: (){
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    ExpansionTile(
                        leading: Image.asset('Image/cone.png', width: 40,height: 40),
                        title: const Text("Honda",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 18,color: Colors.black),),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Image.asset('Image/square-root.png', width: 30,height: 30),
                            title: const Text("Civic",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 16,color: Colors.brown),),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
                            onTap: (){},
                          ),
                          Divider(),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Image.asset('Image/cone.png', width: 30,height: 30),
                            title: const Text("Accord",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 16,color: Colors.brown),),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
                            onTap: (){},
                          ),
                        ]
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
            ),
      ))
    );
         }
```

Any help?

Comment: You need to store the processed JSON in a variable that isn't just local to your loadCarparts function.  So instead of `School carparts = new School.fromJson(jsonResponse);` you should declare a variable `School? carparts` in `_MyHomePageState`, and then do something like `var p =  School.fromJson(jsonResponse); setState({ carparts = p})`.  Now it's in the state, and your `build` method can access it.  In this case you will have your widget managing its own state - see https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive for an example.

Comment: I updated the code. But, the main question is how to change the static method in the code and make it dynamic by getting data from the `carparts` list to the `ExpansionTile` and `ListTile`? I know I need to use `ListView Builder` and loop over the `carparts` list but tried many times and didn't succeed.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your code doesn't reflect the changes yet.  Once it does, why don't you try replacing your complex and static `body` with `ListView.builder(                  itemCount: carparts.length, itemBuilder: (ctx, indx) {return ListTile(title: Text(carparts[indx].Company) );});`. That should give you a feel for how to solve it.